# HTTP 404 The requested resource (/ /) is not available - Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat6

I created a litte 'Dynamic Web Project' in eclipse and try to show/edit/create and delete my data base objects. The tomcat server runs. But I get an HTTP Status 404 Error : The requested resource (/TestDynWeb/) is not available(http://localhost:8010/TestDynWeb). I would like to show all my code files. Maybe you have an idea what is wrong.

### WebContent/WEB-INF:

***Web.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>TestDynWeb</display-name>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>

  <init-param>
   <param-name>config</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <jsp-config>
  <taglib>
   <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-uri>
   <taglib-location>/WebContent/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
   <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
   <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
   <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-uri>
   <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
   <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-uri>
   <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
 </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

***struts-config.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd" >

<struts-config>
    <!-- Form Bean Definitions -->
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="ListForm" type="list.forms.ListForm"/>
    </form-beans>

    <!--  Action Mapping Definitions  -->
    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/showlist" type="list.misc.ShowList" validate="false" scope="session">
        <forward name="success" path="/jsp/listScreen.jsp"/>
    </action>

    <!-- Example of Struts Dispatch Action : has the extra attribute parameter-->
    <action path="/listaction" type="list.actions.ListAction" parameter="actionMethod" name="ListForm"
     validate="false" scope="session">
        <forward name="addObject" path="/jsp/createScreen.jsp"/>
        <forward name="editObject" path="/jsp/editScreen.jsp"/>
    </action>
    </action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

### WebContent/jsp:

***listScreen.jsp***

```xml
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<html>
<body>
    <b>Available Data Base Objects</b>
    <form name="listform" action="/listaction.do">
        <table style="background-color: #82CAFA;">
            <tr style="color: white;">
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Object ID</th>
                <th>Object Name</th>
                <th>Person ID</th>
                <th>Date (Dev)</th>
                <th>Version (Dev)</th>
            </tr>
            <%
                List objectsList = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("objectsList");
                Iterator itr = objectsList.iterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Map map = (HashMap) itr.next();
            %>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="dboId"
                    value='<%=map.get("dboId")%>'
                    onclick="javascript:enableEditDelete();"></td>
                <td><%=map.get("dboID")%></td>
                <td><%=map.get("dboDevName")%></td>
                <td><%=map.get("personId")%></td>
                <td><%=map.get("changedByTimestampDEV")%></td>
                <td><%=map.get("releaseVersionDev")%></td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </table>
        </p>
        <p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="actionMethod" id="editbutton"
                    value="Edit Object" disabled="true" style="color: black;" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="actionMethod" id="deletebutton"
                    value="Delete Object" disabled="true" onclick="return checkDelete();" style="color: black;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </p>
    <script>
        function checkDelete() {
            return confirm("Are u sure to delete this object..?");
        }
        function enableEditDelete() {
            document.getElementById('editbutton').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('deletebutton').disabled = false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***editScreen.jsp***

```xml
<b>Edit Object</b>
<html:form>
    <p>
    </p><table style="background-color: #82CAFA;">
        <tr style="color: white;">
            <td>Object ID</td>
            <td><html:text property="dboId" disabled="true"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color: white;">
            <td>Object Name</td>
            <td><html:text property="dboDevName"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color: white;">
            <td>Person ID</td>
            <td><html:text property="personId"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color: white;">
            <td>Date (Dev)</td>
            <td><html:text property="changedByTimestampDEV"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color: white;">
            <td>Version (Dev</td>
            <td><html:text property="releaseVersionDev"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p/>
    <p>
    </p><table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="actionMethod" value="Save Object" style="color: black;"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html:form>
<p/>
```

**createScreen.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<html>
<body>

    <b>Add Object</b>
    <html:form>
        <table style="background-color: #82CAFA;">
            <tr>
                <td>Object ID</td>
                <td><html:text property="dboId" disabled="true" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Object Name</td>
                <td><html:text property="dboDevName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Person ID</td>
                <td><html:text property="personId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date (Dev)</td>
                <td><html:text property="changedByTimestampDEV" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Version (Dev</td>
                <td><html:text property="releaseVersionDev" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </p>
        <p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="actionMethod" value="Add Object" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </html:form>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

### /config:

***appContext.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=NARTrackingDB" />
        <property name="username" value="abc" />
        <property name="password" value="xyz" />            
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="objDao" class="tracking.dao.DboDao">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

### DAO Class:

```
package tracking.dao;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.objectweb.asm.Type;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;

import tracking.bean.DboBean;

public class DboDao {
    private DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private DataSource dataSource;  // either use @Autowire or provide xml config 

    //private String dboDevName;
    public DboDao() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
    }

    public DboBean read(final int dboId) {//String dboId
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM da_tracking " 
                        + "WHERE ins_ID = " + dboId;
        final Object[] params = new Object[] {};
        //Creating object being queried
        final DboBean dboBean = new DboBean();
        //Process query Results
        jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, new RowCallbackHandler(){
            public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{
                dboBean.setDboId(rs.getString("ins_ID"));
                dboBean.setDboDevName(rs.getString("ins_name"));
            }           
        });
        return dboBean;//returns queried objects
    }

    public int save(DboBean record ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sql = "UPDATE da_tracking" 
                + " SET ins_name= ?,"  
                + " ins_dev_scripted = ?" 
                + " WHERE ins_ID = ?" ;
    Object[] params = new Object[] { 
            record.getDboDevName(), 
            record.getDevScripted(), 
            record.getDboId()
    }; 
    int[] types = new int[]{
            Types.VARCHAR, 
            Types.BIT, 
            Types.INTEGER}; 
    return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params, types); 

    }

    public int createInstance(DboBean record) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sql = "INSERT INTO da_tracking" 
                + "(ins_ID,ins_name,ins_deployed_to_uat, ins_dev_status,ins_dev_scripted,ins_dev_changed_by_timestamp"
                + "change_details,db_owner_ID,type_ID,person_ID,changeType_ID,ins_uat_changed_by_timestamp,release_version_dev"
                + "release_version_uat) VALUES"
                + "( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        Object[] params = new Object[] { 
            record.getDboId(),record.getDboDevName(),record.getDeployedToUAT(),record.getDevStatus(),record.getDevScripted(), 
            record.getChangedByTimestampDEV(),record.getChangeDetails(),record.getDbOwner(),record.getTypeId(),record.getPersonId(),
            record.getChangedByTimestampUAT(),record.getReleaseVersionDev(),record.getReleaseVersionUat()
        }; 

        int[] types = new int[]{
            Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR, Types.BIT, Types.INTEGER, Types.BIT, 
            Types.TIMESTAMP, Types.VARCHAR, Types.INTEGER, Types.INTEGER, Types.INTEGER,
            Types.TIMESTAMP, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR
            }; 
        return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params, types); 
    }

    public void delete(String dboId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sql = "DELETE FROM da_tracking "
                + "WHERE ins_ID = " + dboId;
        Object[] params = new Object[] {};
        //Process query Results
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params);       
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    //Spring setter injector used
    public void setTransactionManager(DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager){
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
        DataSource datatSource = transactionManager.getDataSource();  
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datatSource); 
    }

}
```

--DBOBean.java includes getters & setters--not needed to show here

***ShowList.java:***

```
package list.misc;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ShowList extends Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Show Objects List");
        ListObjects l = ListObjects.getInstance();
        request.setAttribute("objectsList", l.getObjectList());
        return mapping.findForward("success");
    }
}
```

***ListObjects:***

```
package list.misc;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class ListObjects {

    int objectIdCount = 1000;
    Map<Integer, StoreObject> objectMap = new HashMap<Integer, StoreObject>();
    private static ListObjects objects = null;

    private ListObjects() {
    }

    public static ListObjects getInstance() {
        if (objects == null) {
            objects = new ListObjects();
        }
        return objects;
    }

    public void storeObject(String dboDevName, int personId, String changedByTimestampDEV, String releaseVersionDev) {
        StoreObject so = new StoreObject();
        objectIdCount++;
        so.addObject(objectIdCount, dboDevName, personId, changedByTimestampDEV, releaseVersionDev);
        objectMap.put(objectIdCount, so);
    }

    public void updateObject(int dboId, String dboDevName, int personId, String changedByTimestampDEV, String releaseVersionDev) {
        StoreObject so = objectMap.get(dboId);
        so.updateObject(dboId, dboDevName, personId, changedByTimestampDEV, releaseVersionDev );
    }


      public Map searchObject(int dboId) { 
          return objectMap.get(dboId).getObject(); 
      }


    public void deleteObject(int dboIds) {
        objectMap.remove(dboIds);
    }

    // Inner Class used to persist the app data ie. object details.
    public class StoreObject {

        private String dboDevName;
        private String changeDetails;
        private String changedByTimestampDEV;
        String releaseVersionDev;
        private int personId;
        private int objectIdCount;
        private int dboId;

        StoreObject() {
        }

        public void addObject(int objectIdCount, String dboDevName, int personId, String changedByTimestampDEV, String releaseVersionDev) {
            this.objectIdCount = objectIdCount;
            this.dboDevName = dboDevName;
            this.personId = personId;
            this.changedByTimestampDEV = changedByTimestampDEV;
            this.releaseVersionDev = releaseVersionDev;
        }

        public void updateObject(int dboId, String dboDevName, int personId, String changedByTimestampDEV, String releaseVersionDev) {
            this.dboId = dboId;
            this.dboDevName = dboDevName;
            this.personId = personId;
            this.changedByTimestampDEV = changedByTimestampDEV;
            this.releaseVersionDev = releaseVersionDev;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Map getObject() {
            Map objects = new HashMap();
            objects.put("objectIdCount", this.objectIdCount);
            objects.put("dboDevName", this.dboDevName);
            objects.put("personId", this.personId);
            objects.put("changedByTimestampDEV", this.changedByTimestampDEV);
            objects.put("releaseVersionDev", this.releaseVersionDev);
            return objects;
        }
    }

    public List getObjectList() {
        List objectsList = new ArrayList();
        Set s = objectMap.keySet();
        Iterator itr = s.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            objectsList.add(objectMap.get((Integer) itr.next()).getObject());
        }
        return objectsList;
    }
}
```

--ListForm.java includes getters & setters -- not needed here.

***ListAction.java:***

```
package list.actions;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.util.Map;

import list.forms.ListForm;
import list.misc.ListObjects;

public class ListAction extends DispatchAction {
    public ActionForward AddObj(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Add Object Page");
        return mapping.findForward("addObj");
    }

    public ActionForward EditObj(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Edit Object Page");
        int dboId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dboId"));

        ListObjects l = ListObjects.getInstance();
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Map objMap = l.searchObject(dboId);

        // Used form bean class methods to fill the form input elements with
        // selected object values.
        ListForm lf = (ListForm) form;

        lf.setDboId((Integer) objMap.get("dboId"));
        lf.setDboDevName(objMap.get("dboDevName").toString());
        lf.setTypeId((Integer) objMap.get("typeId"));
        lf.setChangeDetails(objMap.get("changeDetails").toString());
        lf.setChangeType((Integer) objMap.get("changeType"));
        lf.setDevScripted((Boolean) objMap.get("devScripted"));
        lf.setPersonId((Integer) objMap.get("personId"));
        lf.setChangedByTimestampDEV(objMap.get("changedByTimestampDEV").toString());
        lf.setChangedByTimestampUAT(objMap.get("changedByTimestampUAT").toString());
        lf.setReleaseVersionDev(objMap.get("releaseVersionDev").toString());
        lf.setReleaseVersionUat(objMap.get("releaseVersionUat").toString());

        return mapping.findForward("addObject");
    }

    public ActionForward SaveObj(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Save Object");
        // Used form bean class methods to get the value of form input elements.
        ListForm lf = (ListForm) form;
        int dbOwner = lf.getDbOwner();
        String dboDevName = lf.getDboDevName();
        int typeId = lf.getTypeId();
        String changeDetails = lf.getChangeDetails();
        int changeType = lf.getChangeType();
        Boolean devScripted = lf.isDevScripted();
        int personId = lf.getPersonId();
        String changedByTimestampDEV = lf.getChangedByTimestampDEV();
        String changedByTimestampUAT = lf.getChangedByTimestampUAT();
        String releaseVersionDev = lf.getReleaseVersionDev();
        String releaseVersionUat = lf.getReleaseVersionUat();

        ListObjects l = ListObjects.getInstance();
        l.storeObject(dboDevName, personId, changedByTimestampDEV, releaseVersionDev);
        return new ActionForward("/showlist.do", true);
    }

    public ActionForward CreateObj(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Update Object");
        ListForm lf = (ListForm) form;
        int dboId = lf.getDboId();
        String dboDevName = lf.getDboDevName();
        int typeId = lf.getTypeId();
        String changeDetails = lf.getChangeDetails();
        int changeType = lf.getChangeType();
        Boolean devScripted = lf.isDevScripted();
        int personId = lf.getPersonId();
        String changedByTimestampDEV = lf.getChangedByTimestampDEV();
        String changedByTimestampUAT = lf.getChangedByTimestampUAT();
        String releaseVersionDev = lf.getReleaseVersionDev();
        String releaseVersionUat = lf.getReleaseVersionUat();

        ListObjects l = ListObjects.getInstance();
        l.updateObject(dboId, dboDevName, personId, changedByTimestampDEV, releaseVersionDev);
        return new ActionForward("/showlist.do", true);
    }

    public ActionForward DeleteObject(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Delete Object");
        int dboId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dboId"));
        ListObjects lo = ListObjects.getInstance();
        lo.deleteObject(dboId);
        return new ActionForward("/showlist.do", true);
    }
}
```

Many Thanks in advance for every help.

Comment: 404 error don't mean 500 ... so Java code should not be a problem. You should probably remove them from your question, in ordre to improve readibility

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have not deployed your application on the Tomcat Server. You need to right click the server in the Servers view and press "Add and Remove" and there add your project to the server.

Answer (score 1):

go to project right click and check Deployment Assembly. Check if the  folder containing web.xml is properly included or not. it may be that you might have configured web.xml in different folder and in deployment assembly Webcontent folder added.

Answer (score 0):

Check that on "Deployment Assemply" there is your WebContent folder. If not, add it.